# Good icon for configurable products

Tags: icons

I have an eshop that has configurable products, what icon would be best suited for marking the products that have configuration in the category listing.

My curent choice is this:

[image]

Comment: I assume you are referring to the icon in the top right of the image.

Comment: @ChrisF correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just add a button with the label "Configure"? Go for maximum clarity and only reduce when you really have space concerns (and even then, you can usually design around it with some degree of flexibility).

If you really have to use an icon, consider [Google image results for "configure icon"](http://www.google.com/images?q=configure+icon&biw=1131&bih=751) which include **wrenches** like you've used (although I'd make the icon quite a bit bigger), but also a fair amount of **gears**.

Comment: +1 on using text. On first glance I thought your icon was a crossed-out implement, meaning the skate was _non_-configurable. You can fix that by making the icon larger so I could see that the red feature is a tool, but then you’ll probably be using no more space than a text label would.

Comment: Yeah, I had that double-take as well.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing a wrench/spanner as suggested by @Rahul is probably the most conventional way to go.

I'd also consider making the icon a little larger so it's more obvious and adding a tooltip to reinforce the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Using text instead of icon 'd simplify user's task.

But, if you use an icon, why not to add a tooltip ("Customize it") fading in when hover upon icon? ;)